# flutter access call logs

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to get my call logs and i used call logs package and on button click, i call tthis function

```
 void calllog() async{
    Iterable<CallLogEntry> entries = await CallLog.get();
    for (var item in entries) {
      print(item.name);
    }
  }
```

but its shooting me an error like this

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(INTERNAL_ERROR, Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference, null, null)
```

PS: i am using this package: call_log: ^3.0.3

Comment: This error seems to be coming from within the Java code of the package. Make sure you have permissions set correctly, then run your app through Android Studio and look at the direct native logging output to get a better idea of what is happening. You might need to post this as a bug on the package's GitHub page.

Comment: well i have already given permission is manifest file

Comment: have you ask user to grant permission access ?

Comment: same here did you solve it?

Comment: check here https://github.com/4Q-s-r-o/call_log/issues/23

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

Add this to your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml file just under the first < manifest> tag.

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to add permission to manifest so operating system will know that your app can ask for log reading. for that, you need to go to:

```
android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml


android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
```

You need to paste this permission under manifest<>

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG" />
```

So, now you have to ask user to grant this request. for that you can use this plugin [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

You can ask for permission like this:

```
void getPermissionUser() async {
    if (await Permission.phone.request().isGranted) {
      getLog();
    } else {
      await Permission.phone.request();
    }
  }
```

Now you can read call logs without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

If the permission to access call logs was denied, this error would occur

Answer (score 0):

This package is not supported anymore and not working for me.
after searching along I found this package from the [flutter plugin](https://github.com/google/flutter.plugins/tree/master/packages/phone_log)
and I made my own [fork](https://github.com/EgHubs/phone_log) and migrated it to null safety and it's now working
check it out as a working alternative